# How to display a name refered by id in tables created by VUE JS?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have database tables below

```
MEMBER TABLE
id (PK)
member_name
family_id (FK)

FAMILY TABLE
id (PK)
family_name
```

I've use Laravel and Vue JS

I success fetching data from Laravel using Vue to display on the browser,

the result I get, MEMBER TABLE look like this

MEMBER TABLE

```
===================================
id     member_name       family
===================================
1      John              1
2      Robby             1
3      Bruce             2
4      Megan             3
5      Lily              3
```

How to display the family column contains the member of family_name(field) taken from FAMILY TABLE

I mean,, how to turn that MEMBER TABLE above into the table like below

```
================================
id     member_name       family
================================
1      John              Doe
2      Robby             Doe
3      Bruce             Lee
4      Megan             Fox
5      Lily              Fox
```

The Code :

Member.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use App\Helper\DataTableViewer;

class Member extends Model
{

    use DataTableViewer; 

    protected $fillable = ['member_name', 'family_id'];

    public static $columns = ['id', 'member_name', 'family_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];

    public function family(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Family');
    }
}
```

MemberController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Family;
use App\Member;
use App\Repository\SearchRepository;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Session\save;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class MemberController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

        return view('member.main');

    }

    public function getData(){
        $model = Member::DynamicTable();
        $columns = Member::$columns;

        return response()->json([
            'model' => $model,
            'columns' => $columns,
        ]);
    }
.....
.....
.....
```

Helper/DataTableViewer.php

```
?php 

namespace App\Helper; 

trait DataTableViewer{

    public function scopeDynamicTable($query){

        return $query->paginate(10);

    }
}
```

THE VUE CODE

```js
<template>
 
 <div>
  <table class="table is-striped">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th v-for="column in columns" class="is-uppercase">
      <span>{{ column }}</span>
      <abbr v-if="column === query.column">
       <span v-if="query.direction === 'desc'">&darr;</span>
       <span v-else>&uarr;</span>
      </abbr>
     </th>
    </tr>
   </thead>

   <tbody>
    <tr v-for="row in model.data">
     <td v-for="(value,key) in row">
      {{ value }}
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>

</template>

<script>
 import Vue from 'vue'
 import axios from 'axios'

 export default{
  props: ['source', 'title'],
  data() {
   return {
    model : {},
    columns : {},
    query : {
     column : 'id',
     direction : 'desc',
     page : 1
    }
   }
  }, 
  created(){
   this.fetchIndexData()
  },
  methods : {
   fetchIndexData(){
    var vm = this

    axios.get(this.source).then(function(response){
     Vue.set(vm.$data, 'model', response.data.model)
     Vue.set(vm.$data, 'columns', response.data.columns)
    }).catch(function(response){
     console.log(response)
    })

  
   }
  }
 }
</script>
```

```html
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div class="container">
 <div class="columns">
  <div class="column m-t-50">
   <div class="card">
    {{-- @include('member.search') --}}

    <header class="card-header">
     <p class="card-header-title">Daftar Jemaat Yang Ber-FA</p>
    </header>

    <div class="card-content">
     <div class="field">
      <a href="{{ route('member.create') }}" class="button is-success is-fullwidth">DAFTAR BARU</a>
     </div>
    </div>
    

    <div class="card-content">
     <div class="content">
      <table class="table is-narrow is-fullwidth">
      
             <data-viewer source="/api/member" title="testing" />
                  
      </table>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card-footer">
    
     <span>TODO : Pagination</span>  
   
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>


@endsection

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: Where is your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is still using EagerLoad from laravel controller or model

```
with('family')
```

and we will get nested JSON data

to filter the field that only display as needed in table
just use .(dot) to refer to the nested Object name
in my case just like this code below

DataViewer.vue

```
<tbody>
    <tr v-for="row in model.data">
        <td>{{ row.member_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.family.family_name }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to eager load your relations.

```
Member::with('family')->dynamicTable();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Update:

To display individual properties, you use dot notation to access them like:

```
<tr v-for="row in model.data">
  <td v-for="(value,key) in row">
     <p>id: {{ value.id }}</p>
     <p>member_name: {{ value.member_name }}</p>
     <p>family_name: {{ value.family.family_name }}</p>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Hi @btl, thank you for your fast response, I have read the docs about eager loading and have update my controller in getData() the Member::with('family')->dynamicTable(), when I load the page, the data shows in the rest of the table outside the table html tag in json format, how to extract the family_name into my html table ? since in Vue using {{ value }} to retrive all data I get confused to implement laravel style like {{$member->family->family_name}} how to do it in Vue component..?

Comment: It will be returned as json so you would use dot notation to access nested objects and properties. For example, `member.family.family_name`. Alternatively you can use array style indexes like `member['family']['family_name']`. I personally prefer the former syntax.

Comment: can you guide me with an example how to insert the nested data partialy in <template> tag on .vue file..? I still don't understand how to insert that data one by one after :  <tr v-for="row in model.data">
     <td v-for="(value,key) in row">
      {{ value }} // shows all data, I need to show the data one by one, eg(id, member_name, family_name) so the family_id not included on the the table
     </td>
    </tr>

Comment: here is the json data "id": 1,
"member_name": "Stenly Rachmad",
"family_id": 1,
"created_at": "2018-01-20 16:29:15",
"updated_at": "2018-01-20 16:29:15",
"family": {
"id": 1,
"family_name": "Lee",
"description": "FA bentukan kak Fanny Lumintang",
"district_id": 1,
"created_at": "2018-01-19 09:31:08",
"updated_at": "2018-01-19 09:31:08"
} I still dont understand to extract only id, member_name and family_name data to <template> tag inside .vue file

Comment: Hi @btl, so you wrap with <p> each value with diferent nested value, I've try it, but still not displaying the data in the browser, and my chrome console shows error that said : [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'family_name' of undefined", its look like vue does not aware that the family contained the data, I have try many possibilities to adjust data declaration in the <script> but still not find any result..

Comment: I have try to insert only value.id and value.member_name, the error gone, but only shows the ID, member_name not

Comment: The `<p>` tags are simply HTML elements I put in the example, they don't affect displaying data at all. I think the issue is in the structure of the `model.data`

Comment: What do you see if you add `console.log(response.data.model)` right before you set it in the response from axios?

Comment: If I can show the screenshot of my pict maybe can describe more clear about the error, but I can't because my new in this forum so not allowed to send image.

Comment: did you mean to code console.log(response) before the axios.get() ? or like axios.get(this.source).then(function(response)){ console.log(response)} , if like so, please look at the very buttom on my question, I have put it the console result

Comment: It looks like there is another `data` property, so `response.data.model.data`. Try `Vue.set(vm.$data, 'model', response.data.model.data)`

Comment: after put response.data.model.data all the data are gone, just left the header of the table

Comment: I'm about out of ideas in that case. JSON.parse the response maybe? Axios should be doing that already though..

Comment: its ok  dude, no problem, I still working to find the solution, I'll post the answer if I found already.. now, I just need take a nap, lol, so many hours I've spend just for try solving this though, my brain feels like fried.. by the way, thank you very much for your effort to help me, @btl, I very thankfull

Comment: By the way, if I only use {{values.family_name}} the name of family are displayed according to the response, since I use EAGER LOAD in controller.. Now I just need to fokus hpw to represent that data to output with the rest of member data.. Thank you @btl

Answer (score 0):

Ok, After reading Laravel, Vuejs and axios documentation, I realize that I don't need to change or add any of Vue and axios code to filter what field to display

So, the code to add it is not in Vue or Axios though, but in Laravel using query builder, just Join and add a specific query for what kinda field that I need to display, because Vue Js and Axios just pull the whole data from laravel db, so be a better approach i think, to specific the fields from laravel query instead

I do the query in the trait DataTableViewer.php

trait DataTableViewer{

```
public function scopeDynamicTable($query){

    return $query->join('families', 'members.id', '=', 'families.id')
            ->select('member_name', 'family_name')
            ->paginate(10);
}
```

First, I join the Members table with Families table according to each table ID, 
then I select, only the specific field that I want to display in my Vue Table and paginate them by 10 data per page

as simple as that, 
Thanks to @alanfcm and @btl for the clues